# How to configure Eclipse TCF to use Powershell on Windows?

Tags: eclipse, terminal, eclipse-luna

Is it possible to configure TCF in Eclipse Luna to use Powershell instead of good old `cmd`?

Comment: problem still exists in Eclipse Mars as of March 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible today (7/2/2014). A (admittedly annoying) workaround is to open up the shell and then execute the powershell command to go from cmd to powershell.

Comment: A nice solution indeed. Thank you.